# Set empty value to numeric text box in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set empty value in my numeric text box but whenever i press backspace, I still get 0 in the input field. Here is the code for Input tag

Here is the code

```
<input
  style={{ height: "calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 2px)" }}
  className="form-control"
  type="number"
  min="1"
  max="10"
  value={purchase.voucherSelected[i].q}
  onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, i)}
  // onKeyDown={(e) =>  this.keyPressed(e)}
  />
```

```
 handleChange(e, i) {
   if (e.currentTarget.value.length > 2) {
     return null;
   }
   this.props.onQuantityChange(Number(e.currentTarget.value), i);
 }
```

`const onQuantityChange = (value, index) => {
   return {
      type: QUANTITY_CHANGE,
      value,
      index
   }
}`[voucher selected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWoYS.png)

Does anyone have a hack for this? Thanks

Comment: please include source code for `this.props.onQuantityChange` and `purchase.voucherSelected[i].q`

Comment: on backspace `if(event.target.value < 1)` did you try with `event.target.value = ' '`

Comment: yes i did. Didnt work

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Not a hack, just plain Javascript
const value = ''
const n = Number(value)
console.log(n)
const nOrEmpty = n !== 0 ? n : ''
console.log(nOrEmpty)
// or
const numericValueOrEmpty = value !== '' ? Number(value) : value
console.log(numericValueOrEmpty)
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know it was this simple